# Is this true that $\mathrm{Tr}(ABC)=\mathrm{Tr}(ACB)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B,C\in M_n$.

Is this true that $\mathrm{Tr}(ABC)=\mathrm{Tr}(ACB)$?

Answer (score 9):

When $n>1$, the equality is not true in general. The following counterexample works for all fields. Let
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},\ B=A^T,\ C=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}.
$$
Then $ABC-ACB=C$, which is not traceless.

Comment: traceless! nice

Answer (score 5):

Try examples!

Let 
$$
\begin{align*}
A &= \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\ 3&4\end{bmatrix} &
B &= \begin{bmatrix}-1&2\\ 1&0\end{bmatrix} &
C &= \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 2&2\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align*}
ABC &= \begin{bmatrix}5&4\\13&12\end{bmatrix} &
ACB &= \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 10\\-3&22\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
Thus $\DeclareMathOperator{trace}{trace}$
$$
\begin{align*}
\trace(ABC) &= 17 & \trace(ACB) &= 21
\end{align*}
$$
This proves that the formula $$\trace(ABC)=\trace(ACB)$$ fails in general.

Answer (score 4):

It is true that $\operatorname{tr}(ABC) = \operatorname{tr}(BCA) = \operatorname{tr}(CAB)$, but not that $\operatorname{tr}(ABC) = \operatorname{tr}(ACB)$.  Someone else has posted a counterexample to the latter proposition.

Forget **square** matrices; just suppose $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$.  Then one can show
$$
\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA). \qquad \text{(Note that $AB\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}$ and $BA\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$.)}
$$
The result asserted above to be true follows from this.

Proof:
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{tr}(AB) = \sum_{i=1}^m (AB)_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ji} \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^m B_{ji} A_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^n (BA)_{jj} = \operatorname{tr}(BA). \qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}

Comment: This is of course true, but it does not imply that tr$(ABC) = $ tr$(ACB)$.

Comment: In the very last summation, the upper bound should be n. However, I cannot make such a small edit (minimum is six characters).

Comment: @Adarain : Thank you. To make a one-character edit, you can write {{{}}} between a pair of dollar signs at the bottom of the posting. It will be invisible if the posting is saved with that intact, and it can also be deleted by whoever approves the edit.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question posted...